# write xml prefix c#

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, prefix

I am trying to create an xml in c# and specifying the namespace and then the prefix on each element.

```
<bk:library xmlns:bk="www.namespace.com/ww">
<bk:books>
<bk:book>
<bk:title>Title </bk:book>
</bk:book>
<bk:books>
</bk:library>
```

I have done the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("library"));
var booksNode = root.appendChild(doc.CreateElement("bk","books","www.namespace.com/ww"));
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

I get something like this:

```
<bk:books xmlns:bk="www.namespace.com/ww">
```

So it outputs both the prefix and the namespace

It doesn't output the xml as I would like it (shown above).

Any idea how I can get the xml to be output like I have shown?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement  root = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("bk","library","www.namespace.com/ww"));
var booksNode = root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("bk", "books", "www.namespace.com/ww"));
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```